# as3 selecting a file dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, file, flash, path

i need to select a video file and convert it to a byte array. the file i am trying to select has been recorded by the cameraUi interface. i can get the path to the file using

```
fileName = media.file.url;
readFileIntoByteArray(filePath, inBytes);
```

when i am passing it into the byte array i need to select directory first and then pass in the the rest of the path.

```
private function readFileIntoByteArray(fileName:String, data:ByteArray):void 
{ 
    var inFile:File = File.userDirectory;
    inFile = inFile.resolvePath(fileName); 
    trace (inFile.url);
    inStream.open(inFile , FileMode.READ);
    inStream.readBytes(data); 
}
```

this leads to duplication of the first part of the path.
i want to keep this dynamic as it will be run on different devices. i hard coded the file into the the variables section of flash debugger and it worked also i get an error if i leave out `file.userDirectory`

thanks in advance any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `File.applicationStorageDirectory` instead of `File.userDirectory`. Due to security risk will vary to vary different device. File.applicationStorageDirectory will work any device.

Robust way of working with filepath

```
var firstPartPath:String = File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath;
var fullPath:String = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("fileName.jpg").nativePath;
var expectedPath:String = fullPath.replace(firstPartPath,""); // "/fileName.jpg"
```

Here expectedPath value you should pass around your project instead of hard code value like c:\users\XXXX\ and save into database also use expectedPath value.

For latter access file just pass only expectedPath.

```
var inFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(expectedPath);
```

Needn't worry about forward and backword slashes. File resolvePath() take care for you.

```
private function readFileIntoByteArray(fileName:String, data:ByteArray):void 
{ 
    var inFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);   
    trace (inFile.url); 
    trace (inFile.nativePath); 
    trace (inFile.exists); //if file present true else false.

    inStream.open(inFile , FileMode.READ);
    inStream.readBytes(data); 
}
```